# How to find call hierarchy for large SOA codebase?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, rest, documentation, visual-studio-2022

Working on a large service oriented architecture solution. Are there tools in Visual Studio that allow to view the flow of calls to different methods?

Ideally I would like to simulate an API request through Postman/Fiddler, and let Visual Studio show me all methods that were called in correct order. Debugging with F10/F11 and finding out call hierarchy for each flow sounds tedious for this large SOA codebase.

I tried Performance Profiler with Code Map extension with VS 2022 Enterprise, but that gave a large diagram that zooms in/out slowly on my otherwise fast machine. Is that the correct and/or only option?

Comment: Documenting new code search feature in VS 2022: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/